# Navigation between ionic pages 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm having trouble with `navCtrl.push`. The flow is as follows:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

n pages' 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3` I can go back and forth as many times as I want, but when I click the back button I need to return on page 1.

To go to the next page I use the button click event like this:

```
(Click) = "quickAccess ('Page1.1')"
```

And to go back I add `navPop` to my navbar` button.

**THE MISTAKE**

When I click on the back, you are returning parts for the pastes of pages `1.2, 1.2 and 1.3` if I have navigated 10 times between these pastes it will return the 10 times.

**ATTEMPTS**

I'm trying to follow the following thinking when I navigate for example from page `1.1` to`1.2` I should remove '1.1`and so on, but I'm having this problem, how do I do this, already tried to index by`View name` but none of them work.

**PLEASE NOTE**

It is important to know that there are other pages prior to `PAGE 1` the flow with problem is only in this case, in the rest everything goes as expected.

Comment: I think you need to use insertPages(insertIndex, insertPages, opts).  In addition to that you'll need logic to describe how pages are linked.  To me you have a tree structure of related pages but each level is considered a new navigation page.  Each new level is a push and each sibling is an insert.

Comment: It is exactly this, but it does not work, when I click remove, it is cleaning my stack, it does not remove only one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

According to this inssue no ionic team:

```
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12238
```

An error is occurring in the structure, a solution for installing the fix via npm as reported in inssue:

```
npm install ionic-angular @ night
```

So my `.remove ()` works perfectly now.